# How to configure "git pull --ff-only" and "git merge --no-ff"

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-config

A typical git workflow for me is to clone a remote repository and use git pull to keep it up-to-date. I don't want merge commits when I pull, so i use the --ff-only option.

I also make local branches for feature work. I want to preserve the branch history, so when I merge the local branch back to my local clone, I use the --no-ff option.

How can I configure git to use those options by default? Currently my .gitconfig looks like this:

```
[merge]
  ff = false
[pull]
  ff = only
```

However, git pull (which is really git fetch and git merge) seems to be picking up the merge option and therefore creating merge.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That shouldn't be the case, according to [the `git-config` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) on `pull.ff`:

> (...) When set to only, only such fast-forward merges are allowed (equivalent to giving the --ff-only option from the command line). **This setting overrides merge.ff when pulling**.

The configuration `pull.ff` has been introduced in Git 2.x, so it won't work as expected on Git 1.x -- it will probably pick up the `merge.ff` configuration and use that when doing a Pull.

Comment: Ha! I knew this worked for me at one point. I recently reinstalled Linux Mint and completely forgot to check the version of git. The 'official' repository is still on 1.9!

Comment: For some reason pull.ff is not listed in tab completion but it works all the same.

Comment: Does this `.ff` option has a per-branch version? Something similar to `branch.<name>.mergeOptions`?