# Git Config Error?

Tags: git, config

Found a weird issue that I can't find on Google.

If I'm working on Branch-A and the origin is on Branch-A, doing a push/pull shows the updated files as modified files on origin. Weirder yet, the modified files are different to the update, it shows the old code (or if it's a new file it says on origin that the file is deleted).

Meaning I have to do a git pull, reset HEAD [file] then checkout -- said file. I'm guessing I'm missing something from the conf file for updating branches when origin branch = local branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution - the cause of the error was because origin was a non-bare repo, moved origin to own server with bare settings and then cloned as non-bare locally, all works now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was not the cause. Git doesn't care much about is the remote repo bare or not (unless you are trying to remotely delete a branch that the remote non-bare side has currently checked out..). The decsription you provided sounds like misconfigured tracking branches that were not refreshed by pull, or misconfigured advanced pull options that somehow skipped the merge phase. What saved your case is the "clone from scratch" that you did: you got default push/pull settings and you've got brand new tracking branches. Anyways - that's great you managed to fix that :)

Comment: This was it seems - I looked into it and it doesn't like having files in the bare repo, moving the origin to a bare individual repo then using the files in a local non-bare repo seemed to have fixed it, it could be to do with tracking set up though - I'll investigate your idea and see if perhaps maybe as you said, the cause wasn't the bare/non-bare fix :)

Comment: if you still have the old repo at hand, please check its `.git/config` file and compare it thoroughly to your new bare repo's `.git/config`. Look for differences in global and branch sections. Also, [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296680/how-to-configure-git-pull-ff-only-and-git-merge-no-ff) - it mentions a somewhat exotic `pull.ff` flag that prevents pull from doing any merges unless they are fast-forward. If you have it enabled, then this alone could result in your "branch" constantly falling behind the remote state even if "origin/branch" tracking branch works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear your cache

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -am 'clear git cache'
git push
```